# Microsoft visual studio express 2013 modify xaml with a visual editor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Is there any way to add components in a drag and drop fashion?

Here is what my environment currently looks like:

[image]

Right now I can only modify what my window looks like through xml, which is undesirable. Is there anyway to drag and drop buttons and stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the file, -> `Open with...` -> pick `XAML UI Designer`, and check `Set as Default`.

You selected the XML Editor as the default for this file type previously, so things like `shift+F7` to change to design view aren't available.  Changing the default back will fix this.

Comment: That option is not there. There's just automatic editor selector, xml text editor, source code editor and notepad.

Comment: then either this isn't a WPF project, or you have XAML options disabled in the visual studio installation.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing some files from the visual studio install.  I would recommend looking at using the newer Visual Studio Community Edition rather than the less feature rich express edition.

Comment: what did you end up doing? did you find an option disabled in your install?

Comment: Nope I just started downloading the community edition, thats fine right?

Comment: yes, community edition is equivalent to visual studio professional, so it will have many more features and options available.  with the express editions, you had to download one for web, one for desktop, one for mobile, plus each of them didn't have the same tools for debugging, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Visual studio comes with Expression for VS, a built-in XAML Editor:

[image]

Check your settings when you open the XAML.  Make sure you are using "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)" which should default to the XAML UI Editor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. I don't know why there's not a UI tab in the screenshot you posted, but pressing Shift-F7 should swap you to the designer UI. If not, a quick web search for "xaml designer" should point you in the right direction. There's also Expression Blend, which is a more robust tool for designing XAML styles and controls. Once you reach a moderate level of complexity, you'll probably start using Blend or hand-editing your XAML more than using the designer.

Comment: When i press shift+f7 it just focuses on the xaml file code.

Comment: You say I'll probably start using belnd or hand-editing my XAML more than using the designer. Is this still true even if my windows desktop application is very simple? Something like a simple utility program where you can select some files from different directories to add to a zip file?